# Could someone tell me what it means error in 406 watson VisualRecognition service?

Tags: java, ibm-watson

How can I resolve this error?

```
 jul 10, 2016 10:47:26 AM com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService processServiceCall
GRAVE: GET https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-  recognition/api/v3/classifiers?version=2016-05-    19&verbose=true&api_key=<key>, status: 406, error: 
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.ForbiddenException:
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have just compromised your service key. As it is tied into your id, any use of it will be charged to you. You need to disable the key as soon as you can.

It looks like you are attempting to list the classifiers that you have created. So have you managed to create any? If you have then I guess that your key is good. If you haven't, then the call should have returned an empty list.

As you are getting a ForbiddenException, this implies that there is something wrong with the API / Method signature that you are invoking, rather than the key. You have some spaces in your paste, make sure that you are not passing these in. The call should look something like -

```
curl -X GET \
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?api_key={api-key}&version=2016-05-20"
```

Which is close to what you are trying, but without the spaces.